# Is internet connection required during Modified time stamp

Tags: windows-7

Can someone explain exactly how the modified time stamp comes to be what it is?
Did the computer have to have internet connection at that precise time?
Is it possible computer was "OFF" at the modified time stamp?
Thank You

Comment: Asking essentially the same question every hour is unlikely to get your question answered any faster. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The date modified stamp is part of the metadata that is attached to the file. Your computer does not need to be turned on nor does it need to be connected to the internet for that date/time stamp to be set. For instance, the file could be modified at another computer then copied to your computer. the metadata would come with it.